# Override Arrow Function in Child Class

Tags: inheritance, typescript, arrow-functions

I use arrow functions in my classes instead of methods because they allow me to use the "this" keyword, and keep the "this" meaning the class itself, rather than the method.

I have an abstract class that defines an empty arrow function that is to be overridden by the child class. Correction, it was originally this:

```
abstract _configureMultiselect(): void;
```

but trying to override that with an arrow function caused this:

```
Class 'CategorySelect' defines instance member function '_configureMultiselect', but extended class 'SearchFilterCategorySelect' defines it as instance member property.
(property) Select.SearchFilterCategorySelect._configureMultiselect: () => void
```

So I changed it to an empty arrow function in the parent class:

```
_configureMultiselect = () => {};
```

But when I try to override that, well, it just doesn't override it, so my `_configureMultiselect` in the child class is empty, when I obviously want it to have a function. Here is my code:

```
interface ICategorySelect {
        multiselectConfiguration: Object;
        numberOfCategories: KnockoutObservable<number>;
        allSelected: KnockoutObservable<boolean>;
        selectedCategories: KnockoutObservableArray<Category>;
        categories: KnockoutObservableArray<Category>;
    }

    abstract class CategorySelect implements ICategorySelect {
        multiselectConfiguration: Object;
        numberOfCategories: KnockoutObservable<number>;
        allSelected: KnockoutObservable<boolean>;
        selectedCategories: KnockoutObservableArray<Category>;
        categories: KnockoutObservableArray<Category>;

        constructor() {
            this._configureMultiselect();
            this._instantiateCategories();
            this.numberOfCategories = ko.observable(7);
            this.allSelected = ko.observable(false);
        }

        _configureMultiselect = () => {};

        _instantiateCategories = () => {
            this.categories = ko.observableArray([
                new Category("Meat", 1), 
                new Category("Dairy", 2), 
                new Category("Confectionary", 3),
                new Category("Dessert", 4),
                new Category("Baking", 7),
                new Category("Grocers", 6),
                new Category("Restaurants", 5),
                new Category("Condiments", 8),
                new Category("beverages", 9),
            ]);
        }
    }

    export class SearchFilterCategorySelect extends CategorySelect {

        constructor() {
            super();
        }

        _configureMultiselect = () => {
            this.multiselectConfiguration = {
                buttonWidth: '100%',
                buttonContainer: '<div style="height: 64px;" />',
                buttonClass: 'none',
                nonSelectedText: "select categories",
                nSelectedText: ' thingymajigs',
                allSelectedText: "all of the things!!",
                selectAllNumber: false,
                includeSelectAllOption: true,
                disableIfEmpty: true,
                onSelectAll: () => {
                    this.allSelected(true);
                },
                onInitialized: () => {

                },
                onChange: (option, checked) => {
                    this.selectedCategories = ko.observableArray([]);
                    var self = this;

                    $('#category-select option:selected').each(function() {
                        self.selectedCategories.push(
                            <Category>($(this).text(), $(this).val())
                        )
                    });
                    console.log(this.selectedCategories());
                    if(this.selectedCategories().length < this.numberOfCategories()) {
                        this.allSelected(false);
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

How do I override `_configureMultiselect` in the child class successfully?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I override _configureMultiselect in the child class successfully

Store it in a new member as `superConfigureMultiselect` and then use that later on.

## More

Arrow function inheritance is covered here : https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/future-javascript/arrow-functions#tip-arrow-functions-and-inheritance

Comment: Cannot get this to work. Could you please do a code example applied to my code? My code isn't the same as in the link in your answer so it doesn't really apply. In the link the parent method has an implementation

Comment: Page not found.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know how to have an empty arrow function in the parent and override it in the child.

For my scenario I could remove the function altogether - it was superfluous. I only needed to override the `multiselectConfiguration: Object;` property.