# Base class invokes abstract method in Subscription

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to ask if it is possible to call abstract method (defined in base abstract class, implemented in instance class) in Subscription also in base class?

E.g. in base class:

```
@Input() observable: Observable<void>;
this.subscription = this.observable.subscribe(() => this.process());
abstract process() : void;
```

in instance class:

```
process(): void {
   console.log('process');
}
```

It is working if subscription is defined on instance class side.

Comment: You can see this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38368203/override-arrow-function-in-child-class which is about overriding arrow functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, it is working I just forgot to call super.ngOnInit() :D

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Methods in abstract classes can call abstract methods that will be defined in their subclasses.  For example, this code works as expected:

```
abstract class BaseClass {
    abstract process():void
    subscribe(){
        this.process()
    }
}

class MyClass extends BaseClass {
    process(){
        console.log("run me")
    }
}

let x = new MyClass()

x.subscribe()
```

See [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmgpgYVXQQG8AoBChUSGeBABygHtYd0AKASgC4A3JgJYATcpTABXcLCgCQOLmUpKEEABYCwAOkYs2YLqIoBfUidIo0GALIBPApYQ4AHhBwA7IRmxh8hDIsodVg5OAOUkJjcwJmQcTWQmAHN2ACIocTcEAFscFM5DBBMzWMQnBABeBDccAHcEW3sQ0lInTQkpGTkuIA).